# Programmatically reduce the sample-rate of uploaded MP3 files

Tags: php, mp3, sample-rate

I have full control of my server, so I can install any plugins or whatever, but that software must be licensable for commercial use.

I want to create a "dulled" version (i.e. lower frequency and bit-rate) of the songs people upload, which will be used for a short while (maybe a few days at most) before being automatically deleted.

This can be done in real-time while it is downloaded, or when it is uploaded; I don't mind if it keeps an original copy on the server. I don't even mind just adding it to a database of items todo, and then just make a cronjob to crawl the todo items and then do it from there.

I don't have much of an understanding of making PHP running programs stored on the server, the most I do at the moment is run the MySQL backup script from PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are gonna download this http://lame.sourceforge.net/ (http://sourceforge.net/projects/lame/files/lame/3.99/) and install it. From PHP, you gonna run the command using the function [exec](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.exec.php) and create a new "encode" of your MP3 in low quality (like 64 or even 48 kbits). After the encode is done, put the output of the encode somewhere the web server can be reach, so you can read from the Internet the result.

Comment: Ah thanks mate, sorted it all out, you da bawss. Id uptoke you but i cant apparently. TY

Comment: @Headchopperz Np, your welcome.